# Load data only for modified url in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-router

I am working on angular 2 project. I have 3 layer routing. It means if I navigate to URL dashboard/projects/timesheet then it will load my dashboard component which has router-outlet which loads project component having another router-outlet which loads timesheet component. There is a parameter pid which loads data on timesheet for particular project. The problem is if I call navigate method of Router class it will load all components from starting of dashboard to timesheet. But I only want to update my Timesheet component.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this functionality, u need to delete your Timesheet component from children declaration in your routes, because it forces components to load 1 by 1 in this tree.

You can specify it separately, with full route to it `dashboard/anything/timesheet`